# Using chromedriver to click on dropdown menu and get table of new webpage

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a code to click on each option of the dropdown menu and then get the content of the new webpage, which has a table. I want to save one file for each option of the dropdown menu.

My code doesn't get these infos right now. I ain't sure if it's possible with chromedriver and Python. Could you give a help?

The website is: http://www2.camara.leg.br/deputados/pesquisa

On the first dropdown menu (below "Legislatura Atual - Deputados em Exercício") you have the name of 513 politicians in Brazil. I should choose one name per time, then select "presença em plenário" and then click on "pesquisar". The table which shows on the new webpage should be saved as a file named with the politician's name.

The same situation happens for the other names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that is workable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
path_to_chromedriver = 'path_to_chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
browser.get('http://www2.camara.leg.br/deputados/pesquisa')
Contact_data = browser.find_element_by_class_name('form-control')
listing = Contact_data.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
listing1 =[]
for element in listing:
    dropdownvalue = listing1.append(element.text)
for i in range(len(listing1)):
    Selection = Select(browser.find_element_by_class_name('form-control'))
    Selection.select_by_visible_text(listing1[i+1])
    browser.find_element_by_id('rbDeputado7').click()
    browser.find_element_by_name('Pesquisa').click()
```

Comment: Here the code opens the browser, clicks on "presença em plenário" and then clicks on "presença", but it doesn't save the table in a file or doesn't get the infos about others politicians. Is there anything missing? Thank you

Comment: @ana I believe you wanted to click on clicks on "presença em plenário" and then clicks on "presença"  i never thought you wanted the entire psuedo code for the table as well.... no worries will eidt and give you the same.